# Install media for gsprint

Tags: ghostscript

I have old media for ghostscript and have been using the gsprint utility for years to silently print pdf files to a print queue for a physical printer.
I have a new machine and wanted to re-vamp the solution and update to current media. I've installed ghostscript by downloading from ghostscript.com and version 9.25 was installed. However when I searched for the file gsprint.exe I didn't find it.
Note: the old solution was a compiled application calling gsprint via a shell. The new solution is to be just a small windows script.
Is gsprint.exe still included? Has it been replaced? Is there possibly a specific install that anyone can point me to?
Thanks!
KC

Answer (score 0):

gsprint isn't (and never was) part of Ghostscript, it is part of GSView 5. GSView 5 can still be downloaded from [Ghostgum](http://www.ghostgum.com.au/software/gsview.htm) though whether it still works is a different question.